# How to unsupport Office 2013

Tags: outlook, office-addins, office-store

I am developing Office addin for Outlook. Although I submitted my app to Office Store, the app was rejected because the behavior of my app was weird if users' Outlook version is 2013. Actually, fixing the problem to support Outlook 2013 is NOT reasonable, so I would like to submit my app to the store without supporting Outlook 2013. Is there any way to "unsupport" Outlook 2013?

Comment: You can change <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3"> to 1.5 which work outlook 2016

Comment: You can find a full list of APIs and the platforms they support at the following link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change minimum support version
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try.